# R plm package and index column mistakenly as a factor, rows sorting

Tags: r, sorting, panel-data, plm

I've a Panel `Dataset` structured as follows:

```
DS_CODE    YEAR    COUNTRY  ...   ...
 671405    1997       AT
 671405    1998       AT
 671405    1999       AT
 30885R    1997       AT
 30885R    1998       AT
 30885R    1999       AT
   ...
   ...
```

where my `index` or `longitudinal` variable will be '`DS_CODE`'; each of these codes have 6 alphanumerical digits (some of them have just numbers, some others numbers and letters, as you can see upper here..I'm new with `R` and I didn't know this could be a problem).

When I use the `plm` package to tell `R` which one is the `longitudinal` variable and the time variable (respectively `DS_CODE` and `YEAR`) the new `pdata.frame` has rows mistakenly resorted in alphanumerical ascending order. Is that normal?
 `DS_CODE` is a `factor`, does it occurs because of this issue?

I would have my rows order unchanged. I already tried:

- converting '`DS_CODE`' from a factor to a character vector (using `db$DS_CODE<-as.character(db$DS_CODE) )`, but then once I use `plm.data`, `R` makes `DS_CODE` again a factor and rows are again sorted in acending alphanumerical order;
- using '`stringAsFactors=FALSE` when loading the `dataframe`, but the `DS_CODE` still remain a factor

There exists a way to use my panel data with `DS_CODE` and his alphanumerical values as the longitudinal-index variable, without any re-sorting?

Comment: Probably best to keep it as a factor, but determine the desired order yourself. See `?factor` use the levels argument to set the desired order.

Comment: Thank you. I realized this was the unique solution, to me at least. It's been a little boring manually setting order for almost 300 levels, I hoped there was another way to solve...but..I did it. :)